# How to update one select option on change of other in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a set of data by which I want to update my UI `select option` but I don't have any idea how I can do that

JSON data

```
[
{
    country: 'India',
    cities: [
        {
            city_name: 'New delhi',
        },
        {
            city_name: 'mumbai',
        },
    ],
},
{
    country: 'England',
    cities: [
        {
            city_name: 'London',
        },
        {
            city_name: 'manchester',
        },
    ],
},
{
    country: 'Portugal',
    cities: [
        {
            city_name: 'Lisbon',
        },
    ],
},
];
```

What I've tried is :

```
                   <select
                        name="country">
                        {data.map((li, index) => (
                                <option
                                    key={index}
                                    value={li.country}
                                    onchange={() => onchange_device(li.country)}>
                                    {li.country}
                                </option>
                            ))}
                    </select>


                 <select
                                name="city">
                                <option
                                    value="city val
                                    >
                                    here I want to show city
                                </option>
                            ))}
                    </select>
```

I am trying to do on-change, but first of all I want to show first option as selected and there sub cities should also be selected next, I don't have any idea how to do this

[My code sand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-mountain-7458h)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refactor `onchange` to `onChange`. You need to assign this prop to the `select` element rather than the `option` elements.

```
<select name="Country" onChange={(e) => onchange_device(e.target.value)}>
```

Afterwards, you can have a state that keeps track of the cities options based on the country that you have selected

```
const [cityOptions, setCityOptions] = React.useState(data[0].cities); // " I want to show first option as selected"
```

Then just map between the values

```
<div className="App">
  <select name="Country" onChange={(e) => onchange_device(e.target.value)}>
    {data.map((li, index) => (
      <option key={index} value={li.country}>
        {li.country}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
  <select name="city">
    {cityOptions.map((city, index) => (
      <option key={index} value={city.city_name}>
        {city.city_name}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
</div>
```

[image: Edit ecstatic-monad-oobyn]